# SQL LIKE complex request AS400

Tags: sql, db2

I am currently trying to write a complex search function using the LIKE query in an AS400 Database.

I want to find all records that have a column SDVR01 which contains 'LIxxxxx'. The 'x' are numbers. The problem is that the column can contain anything like :
' LI12345 '
'LI12345'
'something LI12345'
'any string'

I can't see how to do this with just the classics % and _

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: like Damien said , I already find %LI_____% but it's not sufficiently accurate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable 
         WHERE SDVR01  LIKE '%LI[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

'LI12345' -> Yes
'asdLI12345' -> Yes
'LI12X345' -> No

Comment: thank you but it seems y=that my AS400 can't understand [0-9] (too old i guess)

Comment: in fact i tried 'LI[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' and it works but i can't understand why '%LI[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' don't work, it tells me that the query take too much memory or time

Comment: Zyku has an excellent reply. You can remove the % in end if you don't need to search further.

Comment: I found why !!! My database contain more than 700 000 lines and 20 colums so with only this condition it was too long, and even now it works but it takes 2 secs to return the result

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Foo
WHERE yourColumn like '%LI12345%';
```

**Edit**

Also using wildcard

```
    SELECT * FROM Foo
WHERE yourColumn like '%LI_____%';
```

or a simple `%LI%`

Comment: Thank you, I already tried something like this but if i find a word like LITIGES it will be a problem, but I may use this '%LI_____%' and then apply a regex using code (but it's not really convenient)